# inconsistent space between subfloats in subfloatrow

Tags: spacing, captions, subfloats, subcaption, floatrow

There is an inconsistent space between the second and third subfloat in subfloatrows. I don't understand where it comes from and how to remove it. (OMFSM, MWEs can take a really long time to assemble!)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{floatrow}

%% http://texblog.org/2014/12/04/continuous-figuretable-numbering-in-latex/
%% functionality from chngcntr included in memoir class
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\blindduck

\newcommand{\figh}{21mm}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering     %% centering the subfloatrow doesn't work.
    \RawFloats     %% without it, no main caption. No idea why.
    \begin{subfloatrow}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
            \subcaption{sf1}\label{fig:sf1}
        }{%
            \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-10x16}
        }%
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
            \subcaption{sf2}\label{fig:sf2}
        }{%
            \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-9x16}
        }%
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
            \subcaption{sf3}\label{fig:sf3}
        }{%
            \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-golden-upright}
        }%
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
            \subcaption{sf4}\label{fig:sf4}
        }{%
            \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-1x1}
        }%
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
            \subcaption{sf5}\label{fig:sf5}
        }{%
            \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-a4}
        }%
    \end{subfloatrow}
    \caption{A long caption. Six different images included in the \textsc{mwe} package: \cref{fig:sf1} a 10 by 16 image, \cref{fig:sf2} a 9 by 16 image, \cref{fig:sf3} an image with the golden ratio, \cref{fig:sf4} an example square, \cref{fig:sf5} a downscaled image of an A4 page.}
\end{figure}

\blindduck

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `floatrow` package is not compatible with `memoir`

Comment: I throws warnings alright. I shall restate my question, then. Does memoir support such a feature as rescaling images of different height to the same height and align them one next to the other? Never mind answering that in a comment. I will form a new question.

Comment: You can simply use `\subcaptionbox`

Comment: @egreg thx for the hint. I will research what it does and how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inclined to think of a bug in `floatrow`. If I remove the first subfloat, the wrong space is again between the remaining second and third ones. The behavior repeats when commenting out the new first item:

[image]

Note that there is *no* space when the spurious ones you have in the code are removed: the correct input should be

```
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \subcaption{sf1}\label{fig:sf1}% <--- HERE
    }{%
        \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-10x16}% <--- HERE
    }
```

and similarly for the others.

I think you're better served with `subcaption` tools, taking also into account that loading `floatrow` in `memoir` raises an error. The bug doesn't depend on the class and the behavior is exactly the same with `book`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%% http://texblog.org/2014/12/04/continuous-figuretable-numbering-in-latex/
%% functionality from chngcntr included in memoir class
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\blindduck

\begin{figure}[h]

\newcommand{\figh}{21mm}

\centering     %% centering the subfloatrow doesn't work.

\subcaptionbox{sf1\label{fig:sf1}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-10x16}%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{sf2\label{fig:sf2}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-9x16}%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{sf3\label{fig:sf3}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-golden-upright}%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{sf4\label{fig:sf4}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-1x1}%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{sf5\label{fig:sf5}}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\figh]{example-image-a4}
}

\caption{A long caption. Six different images included in the 
  \textsc{mwe} package: \cref{fig:sf1} a 10 by 16 image, \cref{fig:sf2} 
  a 9 by 16 image, \cref{fig:sf3} an image with the golden ratio, 
  \cref{fig:sf4} an example square, \cref{fig:sf5} a downscaled 
  image of an A4 page.}

\end{figure}

\blindduck

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as every so often: tested and approved!